# pcl:TextureMesh from pcl::PointXYZRGBNormal and pcl::PolygonMesh

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, texture-mapping, point-clouds, poisson

I have got a **pcl::PolygonMesh** as poisson reconstruction from **pcl::PointCloud::Ptr**. I want to create a TextureMesh from both... but how?